# React-native-picker taking up too much of space on IOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, picker

I am developing a screen for my mobile application, which has the search bar, two pickers and a list of cards to be shown to the user. At the top will be the search bar, followed below by the two pickers which will be arranged beside each other. The list of cards will then be displayed below them. In my android device, this shows up perfectly. However, when I test it in an IOS simulator, I see that the pickers take up a lot of height, and only 1.5 cards are displayed in the list. In the android device, the list took up majority of the screen portion. In the IOS device, it seems like that the height of the pickers and the height of the list are the same, which I don't want. How can I reduce the height of the pickers such that the list takes up most of the screen space. Here is my code sample below:

```
return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            {isLoading ? (<ActivityIndicator color="green" size="large"/>) : (
        <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
          
            <Searchbar style={styles.search}
                placeholder="Type here..."
                onChangeText={//some action}
                value={search}
            />
            <View style= {styles.filter}>
            <Picker style={styles.picker}
                selectedValue={searchByValue}
                onValueChange={ //some action
                }
                prompt="Search By:"
                >
                
                <Picker.Item label="  label1" value="label1" />
                <Picker.Item label="  labe2" value="label2" />
                <Picker.Item label="  label3" value="label3" />
                <Picker.Item label="  label4" value="label4" />
            </Picker>
            <Picker style={styles.picker}
                selectedValue={selectedValue}
                onValueChange={// some action
                }
                
                >
                <Picker.Item label="value1" value="value1" />
                <Picker.Item label="value2" value="value2" />
            </Picker>
        </View>
            <FlatList  
                     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                     data={filteredDataSource}
                     renderItem ={({ item }: { item: Item }) =>  <Card item={item} onTap={(item: Launch) => onTapItem({navigation, item})} /> } 
                     keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
                    
                    /> 
            </View>)}
        </SafeAreaView>         
    )
}
```

The styles have been defined here:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    tabContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#dcdcdc',
        marginBottom:1
    },
    filter: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    search: {
       marginTop:7,
    },
    picker: {
        marginLeft: 5,
        width: 170,
        borderColor: 'black',
    },}
```

I have tried by keeping the flex of the tabContainer 1; and then giving a flex to flatlist as 3, and flex to filter as 1. That didn't work as well. I am using {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker'.